# TFunc<T> - is there any way to pass input parameter modificators?

Tags: delphi, generics

I need to pass function as a parameter like this:

```
procedure SomeProc(AParameter: TFunc<Integer, Integer>);
```

When I have this function...

```
function DoSomething(AInput: Integer): Integer;
...
SomeProc(DoSomething);
...
```

...the code works. But with parameter modificators like const, var, or default values like...

```
function DoSomething(const AInput: Integer = 0): Integer;
```

...compiler returns error of mismatch parameter list.

Is there any way to pass parameter modificators, or avoid this error?

Many thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to pass parameter modificators, or avoid this error?

No. The function you supply to `SomeProc` must have a signature that matches `TFunc<Integer, Integer>`.

Comment: How do you recomend to specify this function?
    function DoSomething(const AInput: Integer = 0): Integer;

Comment: You can't pass that function. Write another that wraps it and forwards the call to your non compatible function.

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap it in an *Anonymous Method* like this:

```
SomeProc(function(Arg: Integer): Integer begin Result := DoSomething(Arg) end);
```

Answer (score 5):

Only if you declare it as a Method reference:

```
type TDoSomething = reference to function(const AInput: Integer = 0): Integer;

function SomeProc(AParameter: TDoSomething): Integer;
begin
  Result := AParameter;
end;

function CallSomeProc: integer;
begin
  Result := SomeProc(function(const AInput: Integer = 0): Integer begin Result := AInput end);
end;
```